# Is there any available Alternative of Java parallelstream that still runs thread in parallel

Tags: java, java-stream

I have been using a method with paralleStream() in order to perform some operations on files like translations and modification (different file types and size).
But i have noticed parallelStream sometimes behaves in a wierd way giving me different exceptions or Error outputs printing in the output file instead of proper translations.

On changing parallelStream() to sequentialStream() it works fine. But the problem is , since it is CPU-intensive operations, i need to have better performance in terms of speed.

what is the alternative of parallelstream that would work better than that in such situation.

`Use case : Modification of files`

`Translation of file content from one language to another, so it requires to parsing through each segment in order to do the translation for each segments from source locale to target language locale.`

Comment: If parallel stream doesn't work may be because you are using stream operations that doesn't work well in parallel, for example saving state

Comment: @areus
i am working on file manipulation task, since there might be huge files to be process, parallestream is needed for performance in terms of speed. but this gives me wrong output. i need smtg better that parallelstream but it should work in parallel

Comment: I mean, that reviewing the code you are using in parallelStream can solve the issue. May be the steps you are using are not parallelizable, and hence the incorrect results, that would also arise with another implementation of the same steps.

Comment: ok understood your point, i will have a look at the steps...since m a beginner its bit difficult to figure out, but i wll debug it.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternatives of parallelStream you can try are ExecutorService and Fork/Join Framework.

Υou can find [here](https://dzone.com/articles/forkjoin-framework-vs-parallel) the results of testing the above three options when taking into account different parameters (e.g. number of threads).

Now what is better in each case is relevant to the case and its parameters. As you can see from the results of those tests, parallelStream achieved both the best and the worst execution times. So, it really depends on the parameters of your case.

Comment: thanks i will check the link, and i am using parallelStream() for file  manipulation as in translation of file content from one language to another, so it requires translation of each segments.